# Tab key all the sudden creates <tab></tab> tags in .tsx files. How do I stop this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Tab key all the sudden creates `<tab></tab>` tags in `.tsx` files instead of creating the tab whitespace character.

Tab behaves normally in other file types and outside of VS Code.

How do I change back to the normal behavour?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling all my VS Code extensions solved the problem.